# Virtual Host sub directory redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, virtualhost

I am using the basic install of CodeIgniter. We have a directory structure of:

```
website/application
website/system
website/public/index.php
website/index.php
```

What we want to do is direct all traffic from `website/index.php` to `website/public/index.php`, but we still need `/` to be accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a .htaccess with the following content in your webroot you should achieve what you want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/website/(.*)
  RewriteRule !(public_html) /website/public_html/%1 [PT,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This would redirect all traffic to the index.php to the other one. I need to redirect all access to the website/ directory to website/public_html

Comment: also, I do not want the directory /public_html seen in the url when the redirect happens

Comment: I now have an infinite redirect loop. Since the /public_html directory is inside the /website directory, it results in an infinite loop. How can I get around this?

Comment: one final thing - the redirect works great btw TY! - after the redirect happens, the url shows the public_html directory in it. Is there a way in the htaccess to rename the url to still be www.website.com/index.php rather than www.website.com/public_html/index.php?

Comment: Uhm .. that get's tricky, I'd guess. Try create a new question on StackOverflow. Somebody will know how to do it. I'm not the one I think - sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^website/index.php$  website/public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^website/(.*)$   website/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This only redirects access to the index.php. How would I redirect access to the website/ directory to website/public_html.